# How to save a smart folder jobs marked ok in BMC Control-M

Tags: automation, control-m, workload

Suppose I have a smart folder X having 5 jobs with multiple dependencies. For example, let us assume the job hierarchy is like this:

[image]

So, from Planning tab, I order this smart folder for execution. Since I don't want to wait for Job 202 to execute, as it a tape backup job which is not needed in the environment I am working in, I mark Job 202 as "OK" in the monitoring tab. For Job 302, it is a pre-requisite that Job 202 ends "OK".

In a similar set up, I have hundreds of jobs with similar dependencies. I have to order the folder from time to time, and have to manually mark all the jobs that are not required to run as "OK". I cannot simply remove the jobs that I need to mark ok as they have dependencies with the other jobs I want to execute.

My question is - How can I do this once - that is mark ok all unnecessary jobs - and save this for all future instances when I am going to run the workload?

Answer (score 0):

If the job you mentioned as Job202 is not that important for Job302 to start, then this should be independent. Remove if from the flow and make it independant. Make this changes in Control M Desktop and write it to database. You will not have to make the changes daily.

Answer (score 0):

For all jobs not required in the "environment" you are testing, you can check the check box for "run as dummy" to convert those jobs to "dummy" jobs while maintaining the structure, relationships, and dependencies in your folder. A dummy job will not execute the command, script, etc, rather the dummy job will only provide control-m the instructions on the post-processing steps of the job OR in your case the adding of conditions to continue processing the job flow after the dummy job.

(I realize this is an old question; I provided a response should it be helpful to anyone that finds this thread after me)